# torsocks and Apple's System Integrity Protection

Tags: macos

When I run the following command on Mac OS X (my version is 10.15.6), I got some error.

```
$ torsocks dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
ERROR: /usr/bin/dig is located in a directory protected by Apple's System Integrity Protection.
```

The following is one solution to this problem. But as the author wrote, it is lame. This means that I will need to copy other files in /usr/bin out if I need to make them work for torsocks.

https://lorenzo.mile.si/torsocks-macos-is-located-directory-protected-apples-system-integrity-protection/201/

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution?